# Find the following partial derivatives?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$$F(x,y,z)=x^8y^2+\sin(y^3z^2)+3=0$$

Find $∂z\over∂x$ and $∂z\over∂y$.

I'm pretty confused since I'm only used to finding partial derivatives of something like $∂F\over∂x$ or $∂F\over∂y$. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must think of $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$: $z=z(x,y)$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
0&=dF(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} dy + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z} dz = \\
&= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} dy +\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} \left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy \right) \\
&=\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right) dx + \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \right)dy,
\end{align}
$$
and therefore
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} =0 \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} =0.
\end{cases}
$$
Now you can solve this system and get $\partial z/\partial x$ and $\partial z / \partial y$.

Comment: Finally finished my homework. Thank you so much!